# Stuck Please Help. Void Undefined Identifier

Tags: c++, break

I have been stuck on this program I have created for a while now on this one issue. Nobody has really been able to help me with it. I just want to know how to get the void working as the variables inside are not able to be defined.

```
void PoorRating(Questionnaire RatingDetails[], int i){
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(RatingDetails[i].Rating >=1 && RatingDetails[i].Rating <=3){
        }
        cout << "Information: " << endl << "Name: " << Customer[i].Title << " " << Customer[i].Surname;
    }
}
```

---

```
int main(){
    char AnotherQ;
    int largestgroup;
    Questionnaire Customer[100];//set an array
    int i=0;
    do{
        cout << "Please enter Customer title: "; cin >> Customer[i].Title;
        cout << "Please enter Customer surname: ";cin >> Customer[i].Surname;
        cout << "Please Enter Telephone: "; cin >> Customer[i].Telephone;//set to college the customer's telephone number
        Customer[i].Telephone=ValidateTelephone(Customer,i); //Continues to ValidateTelehpone number operation
        cout << "Please Enter Group Size: "; cin >> Customer[i].Groupsize;
        Customer[i].Groupsize=ValidateGroupSize(Customer,i);//Continues to ValidateGroupSize number operation
        cout << "Please Enter Rating of meal: "; cin >> Customer[i].Rating;
        Customer[i].Rating=ValidateRating(Customer,i);//Continues to ValidateRating operation
        cout<<"Do you want to Continue(y/n)? "; cin>>AnotherQ;//Asks if user wants to continue or end program
        i++;
    } while(AnotherQ=='y' || AnotherQ=='Y');

    largestgroup=FindingLargestGroup(Customer, i);  
        cout << "Largest Group: " << largestgroup << endl;//displays information

    CounterRating(Customer ,i);
    PoorRating(Customer,i);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Full code is unnecessary and you don't have to worry about taking stuff out when you try what you have left and it has the same problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: By the way you have mentioned about what the problem you are facing....

Comment: You have a spelling mistake.  The full error message will tell you what line the error is on.  Learn to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I compile your code on [ideone with GCC 4.3.2](http://ideone.com/13hTKm), I get the following error messages:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'void PoorRating(Questionnaire*, int)':
prog.cpp:68: error: 'Customer' was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:97: error: 'system' was not declared in this scope
```

In your method

```
void PoorRating(Questionnaire RatingDetails[], int i){
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(RatingDetails[i].Rating >=1 && RatingDetails[i].Rating <=3) {

        }
    cout << "Information: " << endl 
         << "Name: " << Customer[i].Title << " " << Customer[i].Surname;
    }
}
```

you are trying to refer to the `Customer` variable, which was declared in `main()`. You probably meant `RatingDetails`.

As for the missing `system()` declaration, include `<stdlib.h>`.

The [code compiles](http://ideone.com/yfaB1R) with the fixes mentioned above.

**EDIT:**
Also note, you probably meant to have the *'rated'* output within the `if()` statement block, and omit the `for()` loop at all:

```
void PoorRating(Questionnaire RatingDetails[], int i){
   if(RatingDetails[i].Rating >=1 && RatingDetails[i].Rating <=3) {
       cout << "Information: " << endl 
            << "Name: " << RatingDetails[i].Title << " " << RatingDetails[i].Surname;
   }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the speedy answer, I did change the program however to the above code. However it now seems to ignore only displaying ratings with 1-3 and also causing me to break at the end step after entering 'n' when prompt. I am continually working on this atm. Any comments or hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @user3361789 That's a different question to ask! I gave you the correct answer for this one, OK? Please step through you program with a debugger to narrow where your logical/run time errors are, before asking another question on SO. See if my edit helps though ...

Comment: What did you intend having `i` as parameter BTW?

Comment: Okay you are good. I apologise for being incompetent, I posted this then didn't expect such a fast reply and changed the way the program was structured. Your solution worked as I entered Customer instead of RatingDetails and also entered the additional library and moved the line into the if statement brackets. I will repost the error code in case anyone else needs a bit of help like I did. Thank you again.

Comment: @user3361789 Your main logic is still flawed. I have edited your question to add the relevant `main()` code, and to demonstrate for you how to post code here (especially don't use tabs!).

Comment: You sound like a cheerful fellow. First time using a website like this. Despite your attitude thank you again.

Comment: @user3361789 _'despite your attitude'_ What do you mean in particular? Have I been rude, or sounding arrogant at any point? I'm apologizing for this, if so, I'm just acting by emphasizing the [policies of this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Never mind its fine. Thank you again for your help. I am still learning C++.

Comment: @user3361789 _'I am still learning C++'_ Yes, and I'm practicing as a professional +25 yrs, and still need to learn. That's not an _attitude_, neither your state needs to feel dumb or so!